# Can't create tables with Foreign Key of each other

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, ssms

Is there a way to create both tables while being a foreign key of one another? I am using  SQL Server Management Studio

[image: error message]

```
--DROP TABLE orders
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    orderId bigint PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(880001, 1) NOT NULL, 
    receiptNo bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES receipt(receiptId),
    productId bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES productServices(productId),
    quantity int,
    dateOrdered datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)

--DROP TABLE receipt
CREATE TABLE receipt
(
    receiptNo bigint PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(900001, 1) NOT NULL,
    employeeId bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES employeeInfo(employeeId),
    customerId bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES customerInfo(customerId),
    orderId bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES orders(orderId),
    paymentMethod varchar(4),
    dateOfPurchase datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The requirement always is: a table **must exist** before you can create a foreign key reference to it. So in your case, obviously, you **cannot** create both table with the full FK references in place, since they reference each other.

What you need to do is:

1. `CREATE TABLE orders` **without** the FK reference to `Receipt` (since that table **doesn't exist** yet at this time)
2. `CREATE TABLE receipt` - here you *can* include the FK reference to `orders` - that table has been created and exists
3. Alter your table `orders` to add the FK reference to `receipt`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.orders
       ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Receipt
           FOREIGN KEY (receiptNo) REFERENCES dbo.receipt(receiptId);
   ```

Of course, the same applies to all the other FK constraints you have - you ***cannot*** reference a table that doesn't exist yet. You must **first** create the tables, **then** you can add the FK constraints.

Answer (score 0):

For you Case, you change the order of creating the Table.
1.) Before adding a `Foreign Key` References to a new table, the table to be refereed as a  foreign key must be already exists.
2.) Also a add a batch Separator `GO` statement while single Execution of creating tables.

```
--DROP TABLE receipt
CREATE TABLE receipt
(
receiptNo bigint PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(900001, 1) NOT NULL,
employeeId bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES employeeInfo(employeeId),
customerId bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES customerInfo(customerId),
orderId bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES orders(orderId),
paymentMethod varchar(4),
dateOfPurchase datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
GO

--DROP TABLE orders
CREATE TABLE orders
(
orderId bigint PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(880001, 1) NOT NULL, 
receiptNo bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES receipt(receiptId),
productId bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES productServices(productId),
quantity int,
dateOrdered datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard because it's wrong.  There's no need for two FKs and they are actively harmful as you could have an order whose receipt points to a different order.  The right design here is to just have one FK, and enforce uniqueness on the FK column.  Thus an order may be created first, and later at most one receipt can be added for that order.

eg:

```
create table employeeInfo(employeeid bigint primary key)
create table customerInfo(customerID bigint primary key)
create table productServices(productId bigint primary key)

CREATE TABLE orders
(
    orderId bigint PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(880001, 1) NOT NULL, 
    --receiptNo bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES receipt(receiptId),
    productId bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES productServices(productId),
    quantity int,
    dateOrdered datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)


CREATE TABLE receipt
(
    receiptNo bigint PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(900001, 1) NOT NULL,
    employeeId bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES employeeInfo(employeeId),
    customerId bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES customerInfo(customerId),
    orderId bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES orders(orderId) unique,
    paymentMethod varchar(4),
    dateOfPurchase datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```